# Strange behavior of fold

Tags: scala, type-inference

What am I doing wrong? Where does `String` come from?

Scala code runner version 2.9.2 -- Copyright 2002-2011, LAMP/EPFL

```
scala> List(1).fold(Map()) { (m, x) => m + (x -> 1) }
<console>:9: error: type mismatch;
 found   : (Any, Int)
 required: String
              List(1).fold(Map()) { (m, x) => m + (x -> 1) }
                                                     ^

scala> List(1).foldLeft(Map()) { (m, x) => m + (x -> 1) }
<console>:9: error: type mismatch;
 found   : (Int, Int)
 required: (Nothing, Nothing)
              List(1).foldLeft(Map()) { (m, x) => m + (x -> 1) }
                                                         ^
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll answer in reverse order:

- With the second error, your need to help type inference: the Scala compiler cannot know the type of `Map()` (it would need to look forward to the second parameter group, the operator, which it cannot do), so it infers it as `Map[Nothing, Nothing]()`. And then trying to add an `(Int, Int)` to a `Map[Nothing, Nothing]` obviously won't work.
- With the first error, you use `fold`, which requires a binary operator, with type `(A,A) => A`, so in your case probably `(Int, Int) => Int`, which isn't what you are looking for since your try to fold into a completely different type: `foldLeft` and `foldRight` can do that, however.

  *Edit*:  it is looking for a `String` because it believes that `m` and `x` have to share the same type, so they have type `Any` (their only common supertype), which doesn't have a `+` method, but it has an implicit conversion that provides it for... `String` concatenation ; so it converts `m` to a `String` and then looks for another `String` on the other side of `+`. I know, this is sad.

You just need to annotate the types on `Map`:

```
scala> List(1).foldLeft(Map[Int, Int]()) { (m, x) => m + (x -> 1) }
res8: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(1 -> 1)
```

Or, to show the intent in a clearer way:

```
scala> List(1).foldLeft(Map.empty[Int, Int]) { (m, x) => m + (x -> 1) }
```

Comment: Thank you, I actually tried `Map[Int, Int]()` with `fold` but was confused by complaining about `String` and haven't tried it with `foldLeft`. Don't understand though why inference doesn't work for `fold`: `scala> List(i).fold(Map[Int, Int]())(_)
res18: ((Any, Any) => Any) => Any = <function1>` and works for `foldLeft`, it could produce more meaningful error message.

Comment: @VictorMoroz that's probably because of the *real* definition of `fold` for a `List[A]` : `def fold[B >: A](z: B)(op: (B, B) => B): B`. The binary operator is only restricted to work on A or any supertype B of A. In your case B can be `Int` or any of its parents, and it seems like inference picks the most generic one: `Any`. `foldLeft` doesn't bother itself with supertypes, there is only A and a target type, so the inference just works.

Comment: Yes, error messages aren't always very helpful when type inference is involved. There is so much dark magic going on in there...

Comment: I think I understand it now. Because I had `List[Int]` and passed `Map[Int, Int]()` to `fold` scala found the nearest common superclass for `Int` and `Map[Int, Int]` which is `Any`. That's why signature is `((Any, Any) => Any) => Any`. And somehow `+` for `Any` requires `String` (most probably via implicit conversion as I can't find `+` for `Any`). `List(1).fold(1)(_)` has signature `((Int, Int) => Int) => Int` as expected.

Comment: @VictorMoroz yes, there is an implicit conversion in `Predef` from `Any` to [`StringAdd`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.runtime.StringAdd), which has the `+` method. You're right about the common superclass thing, I got mixed up in my comment...

Comment: I wonder how often people actually want the default `Nothing` inference. At some point we should probably think of the relative frequency of having `Nothing` inferred when it shouldn't be vs. having it not be inferred when it should be and weigh the benefits.